# Using an outside DNS server to resolve my DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Using the DNS server at Zoneedit.com, I have created 2 sub domains:

> Ns1.example.com *and*
>
> Ns2.example.com

Both Ns1 and Ns2 resolve to my server, which also hosts a DNS server.

If I were to create new zones on my DNS server, could I point my registrar to Ns1 and Ns2.example.com and expect the domains I am the authoritative host for to resolve?

Essentially, Dotster would have to look up Ns1/2.example.com first, and then be forwarded to my DNS server, where the entries would be resolved.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well you want to delegate the DNS from your registar to your own DNS server. So yes it is possible you just have to tell your registar to point to it. You will need to add an NS record and a A record to point to your server and server's IP address

And so you'll will be the authoritative DNS server for your zone.

It should look like this:

registar:

example.com.  IN NS ns1.example.com.
example.com.  IN NS ns2.example.com.

ns1.example.com. IN A 0.0.0.0  ;; ip of ns server is needed because it's the only way for everbody
ns2.example.com. IN A 0.0.0.0 ;; to know where you are

You:

example.com. IN SOA ( ;;; soa blargh!! As it means Start Of Authority you are the one
)

example.com. IN NS ns1.example.com.
example.com. IN NS ns2.example.com.

a.ramdom.host.example.com. IN A 0.0.0.0 ;; ip of a random host

Answer (score -1):

The registrar should accept the IP addresses of the nameservers, not the hostnames.

Comment: -1 because I don't understand. You do indicate hostnames to registrars, not addresses (unless the name server is in the very zone it serves). Also, the sentence about moving from zoneedit is not clear. Read OP's message again, he wanted to move new domains to these name servers, not the existing example.com.

Comment: I missed that he was creating new zones in there.